# Host is unresolved in LAN

Tags: android, host, http-post

Im getting a IOExeption 'Host is unresolved' on HttpPost. The Endpoint in this case a a computer on my LAN with a webservice. (http://pc259:8080/test/service.asmx). Im using WIFI to my LAN. Does Android know to to resolved computernames?

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xmlDataToSend);
se.setContentType("text/xml");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(endPoint);     
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml");
httppost.setEntity(se);         
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
Log.i(TAG, " - Before execute");
httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Have you considered trying this with an IP instead of pc259?

Comment: I forgot about that, yes IP works fine. But i cant use that. I get the Hostname out of a WSDL. I have to use it. (or convert it to a IP, but thats what DNS is for)

Comment: Can you access the machine using the web browser app built in to android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Java to resolve NetBIOS names by using the JCIFS library. You can get it from http://jcifs.samba.org/. Add that to your project and then use code like this to convert a host name to an IP address.

```
import jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress;
...
NbtAddress nbtAddress = NbtAddress.getByName(hostname);
InetAddress address = nbtAddress.getInetAddress();
String ipAddress = address.getHostAddress();
```

Comment: It did as of when I posted. I haven't worked with it for a few years, though, so I'm no longer in a good spot to help troubleshoot.

Comment: @FlashThunder the above code is supposed to return IP Address.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `pc259` is not defined in you DNS server, but is a NetBios hostname (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS#NetBIOS_name_vs_host_name).
I don't think Android can resolve these kind of hostnames - you'll need to add this computer to the DNS repository.

Comment: and how would you add computer in DNS repository.