# Cannot connect using hostname from an Android device

Tags: java, android, linux, sockets

I am trying to connect from my android device to a linux PC using TCP protocol. 
Both devices are on the same network.

When I use a simple java code like this on my other PC on the same network, it works and I get an output

```
class Server {
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException 
  {
    String hostname = "MY_COMPUTER_NAME";

    try 
    {
      InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
      System.out.println("IP address: " + ipaddress.getHostAddress());
    }
    catch ( UnknownHostException e )
    {
      System.out.println("Could not find IP address for: " + hostname);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
IP address: 192.168.1.3
```

When I use this code to connect to a socket on my android phone, it just doesn't work. The handler also updates another TextView for debugging. When I replace MY_COMPUTER_NAME with the actual IP that I can see on my router settings, everything works, the socket is created and the TextView is updated.

```
//Some variables
String hostname = "MY_COMPUTER_NAME";
private static final int SERVERPORT = 5001;
InetAddress ipaddress = null;
String address = null;

@Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
                address = ipaddress.getHostAddress();
                socket = new Socket(ipaddress, SERVERPORT);

                myHandler.post(updateRunnable);

                break;
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }
```

What could be the problem, and what am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think Android has problems with NetBIOS names, but can lookup names that are registered at the DNS Server. see here: [Host is unresolved in LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184463/host-is-unresolved-in-lan)

Comment: Hmmm, the app just crashes when I try to get the address using that code and library. And I have no idea how to setup a DNS hostname.