# Accessing SMB2.1 or SMB3 share from Java?

Tags: java, smb

As Windows 2012R2 no longer supports the SMB 1 protocol without some registry hacks has anyone had any success working with SMB shares in Java where only SMB 2.1 or SMB 3 are supported?

The JCIFS library is apparently SMB 1 only so it is out. I see that Microsoft have a Java library for Azure but this appears to be utilising services rather than SMB.

Answer (score 15):

I found this package that can work with SMB2 and SMB3, named smbj
Take a look at this: https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some off-site resource as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I switched from JCIFS to smbj and wrote a wrapper for it (Contains the most used functions in a file/directory oriented way): https://github.com/swaechter/smbjwrapper

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on @Breakidi answer, I've just used [`hierynomus/smbj` v0.2.0](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj) on Android and added SMB2 support. It claims support for both SMB2 and SMB3 although classes reference only SMB2 versions, not sure, maybe it is irrelevant.

#### Testing

I've tested it against box running SMB2 open in one case and then both SMB2 and SMB3 open in another. I could not disable SMB2 and test SMB3 alone though.

#### Bouncycastle/Spongycastle

There was a need to use Spongycastle in my case (most likely because of Android) as required MD4 dependency was missing from classpath. I've used it within my class that connects to SMB:

```
import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import java.security.Security;
<...>
static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

#### Uploading file

Make sure you set correct flags when call `openFile` on a `DiskShare` (by looking into source code off course):

```
// required imports
import com.hierynomus.msdtyp.AccessMask;
import com.hierynomus.msfscc.FileAttributes;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2CreateDisposition;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2CreateOptions;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2ShareAccess;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.SMBClient;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.SmbConfig;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.auth.AuthenticationContext;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.common.SMBApiException;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.Connection;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.share.DiskShare;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.share.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
...
// connection params
String sambaDomain = null; // can be null
String sambaUsername = "iamuploader";
String sambaPass = "mysecret";
String sambaIP = "192.168.1.236";
String sambaSharedPath = "sharedfolder";

...
// upload method
// usage: upload("file/whithin/folder.txt", fileBytes);
public void upload(String filename, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {

    SmbConfig cfg = SmbConfig.builder().build();
    SMBClient client = new SMBClient(cfg);
    Connection connection = client.connect(sambaIP);
    Session session = connection.authenticate(new AuthenticationContext(sambaUsername, sambaPass.toCharArray(), sambaDomain));
    DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(sambaSharedPath);

    // this is com.hierynomus.smbj.share.File !
    File f = null;
    int idx = filename.lastIndexOf("/");

    // if file is in folder(s), create them first
    if(idx > -1) {
        String folder = filename.substring(0, idx);
        try {
            if(!share.folderExists(folder)) share.mkdir(folder);
        } catch (SMBApiException ex) {
            throw new IOException(ex);
        }

    }

    // I am creating file with flag FILE_CREATE, which will throw if file exists already
    if(!share.fileExists(filename)){
        f = share.openFile(filename,
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(AccessMask.GENERIC_ALL)),
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)),
                SMB2ShareAccess.ALL,
                SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_CREATE,
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE))
        );
    }

    if(f == null) return null;

    OutputStream os = f.getOutputStream();
    os.write(bytes);
    os.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Visuality Systems is currently developing JNQ which is Java-based SMB with as far as 3.1.1 support. Since the requirement contains a backwards support for Java 1.4, the development goes slowly. SMB client will be available somewhere in the coming summer, server will come later.

Answer (score 1):

when use  [hierynomus/smbj](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj) v0.3.0, I get the exception like "`ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.provider.MD4`", then i use the follow code to resolve the problem.

```
SmbConfig cfg = SmbConfig.builder().
                withMultiProtocolNegotiate(true).
                withSecurityProvider(new JceSecurityProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())).
                build();
SMBClient client = new SMBClient(cfg);
```

Comment: You can better use the `BCSecurityProvider` which uses BouncyCastle directly.

Comment: if some one want to get share folders, for now smbj does not suport this feature, then you can use  smbj-rpc on github, when you find problem, you can look at the issue, maybe it will help you.(such as win10 smb2)

Comment: for now  smbj  does not support smb3  just  smb2, maybe future will

Comment: or if you using doman name when connect has some error, you maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184463/host-is-unresolved-in-lan . good luck

Comment: when you upload file to multilevel directory, use like this "parentdir\test.jpg"  not   "parentdir/test.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

There is an other library that support SMB2: https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng