# Java SMB file share without SMB 1.0/CIFS compatibility enabled

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

I have to update an old file sharing software that uses JCIFS for Windows Server 2012. For security purposes, we have to keep the SMB 1.0/CIFS compatibility disabled. Does anyone know of a workaround or a fix or an alternative to JCIFS that can be used in Java?

Answer (score 3):

I've just posted an answer to a similar question:

[Accessing SMB2.1 or SMB3 share from java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494357/accessing-smb2-1-or-smb3-share-from-java/45055211#)

<...>
I've just used [hierynomus/smbj v0.2.0](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj) on Android and added SMB2 support. 
<...>
There was a need for Bouncycastle/Spongycastle
<...>

#### Uploading file

Make sure you set correct flags when call `openFile` on a `DiskShare` (by looking into source code off course):

```
// required imports
import com.hierynomus.msdtyp.AccessMask;
import com.hierynomus.msfscc.FileAttributes;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2CreateDisposition;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2CreateOptions;
import com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMB2ShareAccess;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.SMBClient;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.SmbConfig;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.auth.AuthenticationContext;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.common.SMBApiException;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.Connection;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.session.Session;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.share.DiskShare;
import com.hierynomus.smbj.share.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
...
// connection params
String sambaDomain = null; // can be null
String sambaUsername = "iamuploader";
String sambaPass = "mysecret";
String sambaIP = "192.168.1.236";
String sambaSharedPath = "sharedfolder";

...
// upload method
// usage: upload("file/whithin/folder.txt", fileBytes);
public void upload(String filename, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {

    SmbConfig cfg = SmbConfig.builder().build();
    SMBClient client = new SMBClient(cfg);
    Connection connection = client.connect(sambaIP);
    Session session = connection.authenticate(new AuthenticationContext(sambaUsername, sambaPass.toCharArray(), sambaDomain));
    DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(sambaSharedPath);

    // this is com.hierynomus.smbj.share.File !
    File f = null;
    int idx = filename.lastIndexOf("/");

    // if file is in folder(s), create them first
    if(idx > -1) {
        String folder = filename.substring(0, idx);
        try {
            if(!share.folderExists(folder)) share.mkdir(folder);
        } catch (SMBApiException ex) {
            throw new IOException(ex);
        }

    }

    // I am creating file with flag FILE_CREATE, which will throw if file exists already
    if(!share.fileExists(filename)){
        f = share.openFile(filename,
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(AccessMask.GENERIC_ALL)),
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)),
                SMB2ShareAccess.ALL,
                SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_CREATE,
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE))
        );
    }

    if(f == null) return null;

    OutputStream os = f.getOutputStream();
    os.write(bytes);
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm the maintainer of SMBJ.

Answer (score 0):

Visuality Systems is developing a commmercial smb stack in Java with a backwards support for SMB1. A beta version will be available shortly. VS also provide a full SMB through JNI over their existing NQE stack.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll give them a look.