# Java JCIFS library, performance of reading file is varying on different system

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

Using Java JCIFS library, I am trying to read the files from a remote system using Server Message Block protocol (SMB) as below:

```
SmbFile smbFileTest = new SmbFile(fileurl, authentication); //Takes 20sec
SmbFileInputStream input = new SmbFileInputStream(smbFileTest);
byte[] data = new byte[length];
int count = input.read(data);
```

I am observing the performance of read is varying from system to system. In some system, I am reading the file of 135 Mb in 2/3 second and in some other system its 15/20 minutes.

All environment has Windows 2012 Server R2 and all are running on same network.
Can you please let me know, if any other settings are impacting the performance.

Comment: different network connection? wifi vs ethernet cable? Although 15 minutes for 135 MB is extremely slow.

Comment: I woudn't start using JCIFS for accessing a server, it seems to support only the insecure and dying out variant SMBv1 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494357/accessing-smb2-1-or-smb3-share-from-java).

Comment: do i need to do some sttings, can u suggest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a CACHE issue? when the cache if full it becomes the bottleneck.
Did you try other projects then jCifs? 
BTW this performance issue is the same with ftp or any other Ethernet/Internet protocol?